# Remove line with animation effect in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I want to remove the line with some sort of animation. The problem is when I am setting it width 0 then it is also changing its position. This should not happen.

The line should move from the start point to end point without changing its position.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
$('.main').toggleClass('remove')
})
```

```css
.line{
  width:60px;
  height:2px;
  background:#000;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  z-index:1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.remove .line{
  width:0
}
.main{
  position:relative;
}
span{
  display:inline-block;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background:red;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
  left:8px;
  top:2px
}

button{
  margin-top:60px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<div class="line"></div>
<span></span>
</div>

<button>toggle</button>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8yfLjvu4/11/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you've rotated the line, you also need to change its position so that it doesn't appear to drop down.

Add

```
top:2px;
```

to `.remove .line`.

`2px` to match the span's `top:2px`

```js
$('button').click(function(){
$('.main').toggleClass('remove')
})
```

```css
.line{
  width:60px;
  height:2px;
  background:#000;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  z-index:1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.remove .line{
  width:0;
  top:2px;
}
.main{
  position:relative;
}
span{
  display:inline-block;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background:red;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
  left:8px;
  top:2px
}

button{
  margin-top:60px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<div class="line"></div>
<span></span>
</div>

<button>toggle</button>
```

---

Update: Setting 'top' to 2px was causing a visible jump - turns out `top` isn't affected by the easing option of the `transition`.   What is affected is `margin`.

As there's a 30deg rotation, you can work out the exact values required, but a little trial and error gives a working version using:

```
margin-top:-16px;
margin-left:3px;
```

```js
$('button').click(function(){
$('.main').toggleClass('remove')
})
```

```css
.line{
  width:60px;
  height:2px;
  background:#000;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  z-index:1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.remove .line{
  width:0;
  margin-top:-16px;
  margin-left:3px;
}
.main{
  position:relative;
}
span{
  display:inline-block;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background:red;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
  left:8px;
  top:2px
}

button{
  margin-top:60px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<div class="line"></div>
<span></span>
</div>

<button>toggle</button>
```

---

Extra: changing the `margin` also leads to the requested addition of making it go in reverse.

Again, using a little trial and error, exact values can be calculated based on the 30deg angle, gives:

```
margin-left:55px;
margin-top:15.5px;
```

```js
$('button').click(function(){
$('.main').toggleClass('remove')
})
```

```css
.line{
  width:60px;
  height:2px;
  background:#000;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  z-index:1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.remove .line{
  width:0;
  margin-left:55px;
  margin-top:15.5px;
}
.main{
  position:relative;
}
span{
  display:inline-block;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background:red;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
  left:8px;
  top:2px
}

button{
  margin-top:60px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<div class="line"></div>
<span></span>
</div>

<button>toggle</button>
```

Comment: Thanks man, just one thing can we move it in reverse position. Mean line should go back toward its ending position.

Answer (score 2):

Change `width:0;` to `opacity:0;`

```js
$('button').click(function(){
$('.main').toggleClass('remove')
})
```

```css
.line{
  width:60px;
  height:2px;
  background:#000;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  z-index:1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.remove .line{
  opacity:0;
}
.main{
  position:relative;
}
span{
  display:inline-block;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background:red;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
  left:8px;
  top:2px
}

button{
  margin-top:60px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<div class="line"></div>
<span></span>
</div>

<button>toggle</button>
```

Comment: Something similar I have done but it does not look good. Line should move from one point to another

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('button').click(function(){
$('.main').toggleClass('remove')
})
```

```css
  .line {
    width: 60px;
    height: 2px;
    background-image: url("https://www.stellamccartney.com/cloud/stellawp/uploads/2016/01/1920x1080-black-solid-color-background.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }

  .remove .line {
    background-size: 0;
  }

  .main {
    position: relative;
  }

  span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    left: 8px;
    top: 2px
  }

  button {
    margin-top: 60px
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<div class="line"></div>
<span></span>
</div>

<button>toggle</button>
```

Try using a `background-image` instead of colour and then reduce the `background-size` from 100% to 0 by keeping `background-repeat` to `no-repeat`. This will give you the desired effect